# Post date vs. event date in Wordpress

Tags: events, date, order

If I'm creating a WordPress site, what should I do when I have a blog that manages events to keep date events? For instance, in my own case, I'm making a travel blog where some histories have a real date (when I visit some place), but are published in a later date (when I'm at home). I'd like to show the *real* date but if I set this real date as the post date, the post order is a chaos (I have events that are directly hidden and never showed in the home page, because the date is not among the latest 10 posts).

What should I do? Is there any plugin to help with that? Or maybe I can change my theme listing the posts in a different manner, but how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about a plugin, but you can definitely add custom meta that allows you to set the event date, or even an event daterange (my preferred way of handling this is an event date and a duration, cuts down on calculations in the backend and is generally easier to understand, but ymmv). This allows you to keep your post dates in order while maintaining event dates, and also allows you to query by either of them using WP_Query, should you have that need.

Comment: Absolutely. Post custom meta data is the appropriate place for "Event" meta data such as event date.

Comment: +1 I'd add that for more involved event management a plug-in would make more sense (and be more efficient). For the purpose in the question, meta data would be the way to go.

Comment: Perfect. I didn't used custom fields before. Using "custom field suite" makes it easier to users.